# Jenkins + Credentials Plugin Setup

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am new to Jenkins. I am trying to setup Credentials based on wiki provided by this plugin developer.

Following Setup,

Jenkins 1.634
OS X Yosemite 10.10.5
Chrome Browser
JAVA 1.8

I have gone through below steps.

1. I have downloaded latest Jenkins i.e. 1.634
2. Start jenkins and open jenkins on Chrome browser.
3. Click on Credentials link on left side menu.
4. Click on Global Credentials.
5. Click on Setup two Credentials
6. Create new job
7. Select SVN as Source Management
8. Entered Repository URL

But Jenkins does not show any dropdown for credentials selections. I have tried various combination but could not get it.

Can please help to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Shailendra Soni

Comment: Question. After you save the credentials under the credentials screen, navigate to the job, and then navigate back to the credentials screen, are the credentials still there?

Comment: Yes, all credentials are there. Anyway I found answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of my question.

I need to installed the all relevant plugins which are having touch point of credentials. All those plugins are references on Credentials Plugin page.

Comment: Could you please share the contents of your plugins.txt? That would be a great addition to your question's answer.